# UA and HITs in topos theory.

Tags: soft-question, category-theory, topos-theory

What is an example of $(\infty,1)$-topos that does not admit univalence axiom or HITs? I'll also appreciate related articles/books.

Comment: Please add some more details to this question. What is the context and your motivation for asking this question? You might also want to include some pointers to relevant definitions via an [edit]